# Design an iOS SDK to display a UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, sdk, frameworks

I am currently developing an iOS SDK which is supposed to provide some UIViewControllers for different tasks and I am struggling to find a nice design.

In my opinion there are 3 possible designs:

1. Let the user of the SDK instantiate an configure an instance of the SDK UIViewController and let him/her present it
2. Provide a class method to show the UIViewController which takes care of presenting and dismissing
3. Implement a Builder Pattern to configure an instance of the desired UIViewController and then either let the user present the ViewController or call a show on the Builder

Each of these solutions have some drawbacks. With Solution 1 I cannot know if a navigation controller will be used to display the controller (or if a navigation bar is available) and I would need to implement some custom stuff to add buttons etc. which normally can be found in the navigation bar.

Solution 2 is not very configurable and needs the user to pass a parent UIViewController to display a UIViewController.

It would be great if someone could point me to a link or give some advice on this matter. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess that GameKit during authentication is a good example. If authentication fails in the callback block you'll have the opportunity to display and instance of a view controller to register or login to game center.
Here is a sample:

```
- (void) authenticateLocalPlayer
{
    GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error){
         if (viewController != nil)
         {
             [self showAuthenticationDialogWhenReasonable: viewController
         }
         else if (localPlayer.isAuthenticated)
         {
             [self authenticatedPlayer: localPlayer];
         }
         else
         {
             [self disableGameCenter];
         }
     }];
}
```

As you can see the view controller is created by game center framework, but the decision to display and how (push, modal, etc) is given to the dev. I guess that is the best solution.